# Python HTTP Basic Authentication through Selenium when username and password contains special characters

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, windows-authentication, basic-authentication

I have a very specific problem when trying to use default Selenium auth using this construction `username:password@siteurl.com`
**So here is an issue:** if I use a password like this `"''asd'asd';123asd'` (with specific symbols) `traceback` will say that `URL` is incorrect. But if the password is just with numbers and letters -- everything is OK.
Below is an example of a code that works correctly but for my example, I need to fill password with a lot of specific symbols and I don't have permission to change it.

```
import unittest
from selenium import webdriver


class LoggedTest(unittest.TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUp(inst):
        # create a new Chrome session """
        inst.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        inst.driver.implicitly_wait(30)
        inst.driver.maximize_window()

        # navigate to the application home page """
        inst.driver.get("http://admin:admin@theinternet.herokuapp.com/basic_auth")
```

Comment: Try `driver.get('http://admin:%22%27%27asd%27asd%27%3B123asd%27@theinternet.herokuapp.com/basic_auth')`.  You can use [URL-encoder](https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/) to encode/decode special characters

Comment: This case work too, thanks.
So main issue was with UTF encoding, now I know how to play with that.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For *Basic Authentication* if the *Password* contains **symbols** e.g. `"''asd'asd';123asd'` you need to [**translate**](https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/) the *string* into **UTF**. As an example:

```
username = "%21%40user" #stands for !@user
password = "%0D%0Apass" #stands for ^&pass
webpage = "something.url.com"
```

Now you can use:

```
url = 'http://{}:{}@{}'.format(username, password, webpage)
driver.get(url)
```