# How to manage Basic Authentication login with selenium c#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, basic-authentication

I'm making tests for the company where i'm doing my intership, but i don't know how to make that the script put my credentials in [this part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hKdxd.png), if i enter in the page(myself, not the chromedriver) automatically gets the credentials from the login on my pc, obviously the test driver can't do that, that's why i get that alert, my question is how can i put the credentials there automatically? for now i'm putting a thread sleep and putting the credentials manually but i know that's not the optimal way to do it, i already try using the alert methods:

```
var alert = driver.SwitchTo().Alert();
alert.SetAuthenticationCredentials("user","password");
alert.Accept();
```

But I get this error:

```
Message: OpenQA.Selenium.NoAlertPresentException : no such alert
(Session info: chrome=87.0.4280.141)
```

And if i put a wait i got a timeout but nothing happen, as you can see i'm using chrome, i read a post  from some years that chrome can't manage alerts, but i don't know if that's a thing today, i hope you guys can help me.

Comment: Has anybody tried using chrome devtools with Selenium 4rc with c#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After days on research and trying, this is what works for me, i did a Google Chrome extension, the basic authentication method of http://user:password@mywebsite.com don't work anymore so i did this extension with my credentials, it's kinda risky but it was the only solution that i found

First you need to make a manifest.json:

```
{
  "name": "Webrequest API",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Extension to handle Authentication window",
  "permissions": [
    "webRequest",
    "webRequestBlocking",
    "<all_urls>"
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": [
      "webrequest.js"
    ]
  },
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

Then you need to create webrequest.js:

```
chrome.webRequest.onAuthRequired.addListener(function(details){
        console.log("chrome.webRequest.onAuthRequired event has fired");
        return {
                authCredentials: {username: "myusername", password: "mypassword"}
            };
    },
    {urls:["<all_urls>"]},
    ['blocking']);
```

After that you need to create the crx, in the chrome://Extension site in developer mode, after that you should login without problem in the website you're trying to login.

References:
[How to handle authentication popup in Chrome with Selenium WebDriver using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42114940/how-to-handle-authentication-popup-in-chrome-with-selenium-webdriver-using-java?noredirect=1&lq=1)

I hope help to anyone who come to this post

Answer (score 2):

It's not an *alert* as such but the **Basic Authentication** popup.

---

### Solution

You can access the url passing the *username* and *password* embedded within the url as follows:

```
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://<username>:<password>@website.com/");
```

As an example to login within [**Basic Auth**](http://the-internet.herokuapp.com/basic_auth) you can use:

```
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://admin:admin@the-internet.herokuapp.com/basic_auth");
```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [Selenium - Basic Authentication via url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45345882/selenium-basic-authentication-via-url/45352660#45352660)
- [Python Windows Authentication username and password is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45328654/python-windows-authentication-username-and-password-is-not-working/45329228#45329228)

Comment: I add it but the same login appear, and don't show any error about the credentials or something like that, it's like the credentials in the link doesn't exist, there is a problem if i have a "+" in my password?

Comment: @FreyreGonzalez `+` in password. you have to handle it differently. Check the discussion [Python HTTP Basic Authentication through Selenium when username and password contains special characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53371250/python-http-basic-authentication-through-selenium-when-username-and-password-con/53371455#53371455)