# C# Selenium ChromeDriverService throwing SSL related error on windows 11 OS for loading web site

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, ssl, ssl-certificate, windows-11

I have a small c# console program which load list of URL one by one using Selenium and parse some text data. our program run successfully on **window 10 OS** but when running my program on **windows 11 OS** then getting this error message:

[image: see my error message screen shot]

from the error image it seems the error is related to SSL, but not sure.

I am sharing bit of my code that how i am loading web site using chrome.

```
string _dowLoginUrl = "https://newsplus.wsj.com/";
var chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.AddArguments("headless");
chromeOptions.Proxy = null; 

ChromeDriverService chromeservice = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService(_chromeDriver);
chromeservice.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;
Idriver = new ChromeDriver(chromeservice, chromeOptions); 
Idriver.Manage().Cookies.DeleteAllCookies();
Idriver.Navigate().GoToUrl(Url);   
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(4000);
```

login to site programmatically this way

```
var loginBox = Idriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@id='email']"));
loginBox.SendKeys("userid@mysite.com");
var pwBox = Idriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@id='password']"));
pwBox.SendKeys("password123");
var signinBtn = Idriver.FindElement(By.ClassName("basic-login-submit"));
signinBtn.Click();
```

1. To over come this issue i used **ServicePointManager** like this way

```
ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 9999;
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls
       | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11
       | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
       | SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback +=
(sender, cert, chain, error) =>
{
    return true;
};
```

after adding above line same error message I am getting.

my second try as follows

I add this chrome option later

```
chromeOptions.AddArguments("ignore-certificate-errors");
```

but still no luck; I'm having the same error message.

What i need to set or change in settings of **windows 11**?

Comment: Read the error message. Message says connection completed so it is not a TLS issue.  The error is failing during login.  The error is due to either Authentication or Credentials.  The is more than one type of credentials.  You may be using either Windows (basic) or OAUTH2.  See : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65689725/how-to-manage-basic-authentication-login-with-selenium-c/65691200#65691200

Comment: This way application login to the site `var loginBox = Idriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@id='email']"));
loginBox.SendKeys("userid@mysite.com");
var pwBox = Idriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@id='password']"));
pwBox.SendKeys("password123"); Main code updated`

Comment: Put break point on code and see where it is failing.  TLS is performed before the http request is sent.  Since Net 4.7.1 TLS is performed in the OS and not in Net by default unless you specify the Net/Core should be used.  The code you added is probably making issue worse and instead of failing Credentials you are failing early on TLS.  Remove the Service Point Code and fix the real issue.  Win 11 is probably not accepting an unencrypted password and you need to encrypt the password by using credentials (or default credentials).