# Windows Authentication with username and password to a URL with special characters

Tags: java, security, selenium-webdriver, url, windows-authentication

I have a URL (let's just call it `my.url.com`).  I am using Selenium with Java for automation.  This URL requires a login and password to log in, but it uses a Windows login/password so Selenium can't access it.  I read I could do an `http://login:password@my.url.com`.  The problem is, say the user is `tony` and the password is `ch@mberlain`.  This has an `@` so it confuses the url:

```
http://tony:ch@mberlain@my.url.com
```

I read you could escape it so I tried a

```
http://tony:ch%40mberlain@my.url.com
```

but that did not work either.

Do I need something like a semicolon

```
http://tony:ch%40;mberlain@my.url.com
```

or brackets

```
http://tony:ch{%40}mberlain@my.url.com
```

or so?  How do I get it to work?  The error is security error.

```
Failed to navigate to XXXXXX. This usually means that a call to the COM method IWebBrowser2::Navigate2() failed. The error returned is: Received error: 0x800c000e ['A security problem occurred.']
```

(As this is a company URL I had to remove it for confidentiality and replace with Xs.  The `my.url.com` was just for the example).

Any idea what to do?  This is running Edge with IE compatibility. Altering the password is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

Incase using [*Basic Authentication*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53371455/7429447) if the *Windows login/password* contains symbols e.g. `ch@mberlain` you need to [***Decode/Encode***](https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/) the *string* as follows:

```
ch@mberlain -> ch%40mberlain
```

---

### This usecase

In your usecase you need to:

```
driver.get("http://tony:ch%40mberlain@my.url.com");
```

Comment: I did try that (shown above) but same problem